# Delete any polygon that overlaps polygons on another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select, select-by-expression

I'm new to GIS software and I couldn't find an answer here for QGIS specifically.

I have layer A with a few thousand polygons that have the attribute "Field". I have layer B which is a polygonized raster layer with... An ungodly number of tiny dot-like polygons (They're not points, they're just a km square). Many of these dots are on top of elements from layer A.

How can I select all polygons on Layer B which overlap with polygons on layer A? I do not want to dissolve and clip, as that makes the polygons touch. I want at least some space between them (100 m would be fine), and the best way seems to be "Select all overlapping, delete".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select within distance
2. Toggle Editing, delete and save edits

[image]

Comment: Optionally: invert selection and export - I prefer not destroy the source of truth data.